# Which solution is better in order to develop Front in Angular + Microservices arquitecture in .NET Core?

Tags: angular, .net-core

In the past we have projects using monolith arquitecture with .NET Framework and MVC. Now we are moving to Angular+NET Core. I have two ways to do this:

-First, creating the Front with the Angular CLI and after that connect to .NET Core APIRest serving the JSON. The APIRest is developed alone in a solution of Visual Studio.

-The second one is doing both in the same solution of Visual Studio as .NET Core + Angular web application.

For the future I think the first one is the best, because you could change the front end in a easier way and also the repositories would be differents, the deployment would be easier etc. But some people say that the best practise is to do the second alternative. In my opinion this would go to a monolith in the future, yes you can split the folders and so on but I think creating a proyect in Visual Studio like that would be heavier and a lot of dependencies which will be not used, that is why I prefer to split the development.

Which one is the most recomended one and what are the pros/cons?

Thanks in advance

Comment: personally i'd prefer the first solution, since there's already a backend and so it's better in terms of separation of concerns, but this question is quite opinion based, like you already noticed and by that off-topic for stackoverflow

Comment: @AlleXyS this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first solution has number of advantage**s,

1. The first solution is not developing tightly coupled solution between UI/Presentation and API layer. This is loosely coupled solution and hence both can change easily in longer term (as you already mentioned). This is also taking care of separation of concern.
2. Secondly, having separate solution having lesser concern during merge operation.
3. Many a times angular published files are static files which may not require web server to serve and to increase the speed can be served from Aws s3, Azure blob; can be cached in cdn. So the user need not reach to your web server first to download the files and then make api calls to get data.
4. Works well with large teams, separate teams (like frontend/backend)

**Disadvantages for the first solution** will be,

1. You have to maintain 2 pipelines (from repo to deployment)
2. UI/Presentation deployment required to be in sync with API deployment. You cannot deploy UI before API, else UI will not receive any data.
3. Debug: During local debug, You need to open 2 solutions and make sure  both are having latest code or same version; else you may close a bug ticket with old API but in reality UI is breaking with latest API.

**The second solution might be good**, if it's an one time activity or if your are not expecting it to grow fast or change rapidly anytime in future, like may be a fewer changes in a year; also 1/2 devs are working etc. You need not maintain multiple repo, pipeline. In single solution, once you pulled the latest code you can always know the development state like if API development is finshed or not and lesser chances that your UI and API are not having latest code..